# Avoid QR/Barcode duplicates for fake product identification

Tags: mobile, qr-code, barcode

I'm developing an app for a college project to detect fake products. The idea is to scan a QR or barcode and the app will automatically tell you if the product is either original or fake.

How to avoid the duplication of a QR or barcode, so each one is unique and cannot be modified? I was thinking of implementing blockchain technology with smart contracts but I want to hear other possible solutions.

Comment: I have done some research and the idea is similar to kaiosID or Certus seal

Comment: You cannot prevent copying a QR or barcode and putting it on something else (like a fake product). It's just an image without inherent context. Blockchain or whatever fancy stuff you propose can be used to verify that the code was properly issued, but does not prevent a copy.

Comment: Barcodes and QR codes are just representations of strings. So, your plan needs to work if you just print the string on the product. There is no magic or logic in barcodes or QR codes, it's just encoding ... So your question becomes "how can I prevent a string from being copied?" You can see how that just won't work.

Comment: There is no solution of it. The entire product can be cloned. The only solution is to maintain premium quality which is hard to replicate in cheap knock offs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both of these things:

1. Put the barcode under a scratch-off coating like lottery tickets and gift card PINs have.
2. When someone validates the barcode, instead of just showing whether it's real, also show whether anyone has ever scanned it before.

Comment: That's only relevant if you want to protect the first scan. And you don't need a bar code for that. Any string would do. This is no different than a code to register a product or gift card. This won't determine if the code is meant to be there.